# ASP.NET Core: Being an external authentication source for other applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core

In ASP.NET Core, it's easy enough to use external authentication services for allowing users to sign into a web application (MS, Facebook, and Google accounts are supported out of the box).

However, how can I go about setting my application up to actually *be* an external authentication provider for other web apps that I'm writing? I haven't as of yet been able to find any examples of this online. Ideally, I would like one core application to store the main user accounts, and then have other applications sign in with those accounts, in the same way that signing in with any other external account would work.

I understand that this could probably be accomplished by sharing the Identity database between accounts and have them use all the same users directly, but ideally an OAuth2 style solution would be preferable for clean separation. Is there any nice "out of the box" way to do this, or is it not a well supported scenario?

Comment: http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ryan, thinktecture 'identityserver4' is what u can use. It is an oauth and openid provider hosted in asp.net core pipeline. Heaps of resources on his site. It is recommended by asp.net core team.

Comment: Thanks, this led me to https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server

and http://leastprivilege.com/2015/07/22/the-state-of-security-in-asp-net-5-and-mvc-6-oauth-2-0-openid-connect-and-identityserver/

which should get me through. I'll mark you as the answer until I can write up a full post on the implementation.